# Error: No Auth-Type found: rejecting the user via Post-Auth-Type = Reject, Freeradius got this error when try to connect remotely

Tags: ubuntu, freeradius

I setup `freeradius` and `daloradius` in my one ubuntu machine and also setup `softether` in my another ubunut machine.

I created a user in freeradius using daloradius:

```
Username: elastic
Password: mypassword
Password Type: Cleartext-password
```

when I check my radcheck table I get my user details:

```
MariaDB [radius]> SELECT * FROM radcheck;
+----+----------+--------------------+----+-------------+
| id | username | attribute          | op | value       |
+----+----------+--------------------+----+-------------+
|  1 | elastic  | Cleartext-Password | := | mypassword |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

When Test the user connectivity using daloradius

```
config > maintenance > Test user connectivity.
```

I got this:

```
Executed:
echo User-Name='elastic',User-Password='mypassword' | radclient -c '1' -n '3' -r '3' -t '3' -x '127.0.0.1:1812' 'auth' 'testing123' 2>&1

Results:
Sent Access-Request Id 3 from 0.0.0.0:41818 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 47
User-Name = "elastic"
User-Password = "mypassword"
Cleartext-Password = "mypassword"
Received Access-Accept Id 3 from 127.0.0.1:1812 to 0.0.0.0:0 length 20

I also created a user named as `elastic` in the softether vpn server and set the authentication type for that particular user RADIU authentication
```

and when I try to connect using my softether vpn client, I got this error (running freeradius in debugging mode **sudo freeradius -X -i 0.0.0.0 -p 1812**):

```
Ready to process requests
(5) Received Access-Request Id 11 from 10.66.0.42:60353 to 10.66.0.43:1812 length 146
(5)   User-Name = "elastic"
(5)   User-Password = "mypassword"
(5)   NAS-Identifier = "SoftEther VPN Server"
(5)   Service-Type = Framed-User
(5)   NAS-Port-Type = Virtual
(5)   Tunnel-Type:0 = PPTP
(5)   Tunnel-Medium-Type:0 = IPv4
(5)   Called-Station-Id = "stage-hub"
(5)   Calling-Station-Id = "98.234.185.239"
(5)   Tunnel-Client-Endpoint:0 = "98.234.185.239"
(5)   Proxy-State = 0x4c323a534556504e
(5) ERROR: No Auth-Type found: rejecting the user via Post-Auth-Type = Reject
(5) Failed to authenticate the user
(5) Using Post-Auth-Type Reject
(5) Post-Auth-Type sub-section not found.  Ignoring.
(5) Delaying response for 1.000000 seconds
Waking up in 0.3 seconds.
Waking up in 0.6 seconds.
(5) Sending delayed response
(5) Sent Access-Reject Id 11 from freeradius-ip:1812 to softether-vpn-id:60353 length 30
(5)   Proxy-State = 0x4c323a534556504e
Waking up in 3.9 seconds.
(5) Cleaning up request packet ID 11 with timestamp +54
```

I know this is a pretty common error but I am really stuck at this over an week now.

so what I am doing wrong here.